# Create Pandas Dataframe from List of Dictionaries with missing keys

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

say for example:

```
d1={'a':1, 'b':2, 'c':3}
d2={'b':5, 'd':10}
d3={'e':7, 'a':8}
```

and I would like to create a df which can look like this:

[intended outcome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N9su2.png)

I know one way to do it is to update the dictionaries first by eg. d1['d']=d1.get('d', None) but I do not have an exhaustive list of keys.
Is there any simple way to achieve my intended outcome?

Comment: Maybe: `pd.DataFrame([d1, d2, d3])`

Comment: Try `pd.DataFrame([d1, d2, d3])`, or in general, `pd.DataFrame(list_of_row_dicts)`.

Comment: omg I didn't know Pandas can do the matching by itself